# SSRS Line Graph formatting

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

Environment: Windows 8.1, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database, SQL Server 2008 R2 BIDS
Database: Performance counter data collected on client servers. The particular values involved in this question are % Processor Time and Batch Request/sec.

I did not start this report from scratch. I am actually just modifying one Allen White provided from his TechEd 2010 session that you can find [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/allen_white/archive/2010/06/13/teched-2010-followup.aspx). I am using the same table structure with a few modifications to column names and such for my liking, pretty much the same other than that. I also added some filter/parameters into the report because I have multiple servers in this database.

I take the RDL file and import it into my SSRS project. Modify the procedures and column names to match my setup. I noted the format of the graph to be a simple line graph:
[image]

The border for each series is set to a solid line style with 2pt line width, no shadow. I don't see why I don't get a pretty line versus this. Is there some format setting I am missing? It has been sometime since I have tried setting up graphs in BIDS.
[image]

Comment: Could it be that your data is pants? That or your bottom axis is too scrunched. If you do a top N (something in the tens) for your query sources, does that make it look less bad?

Answer (score 1):

Always enjoy getting help from this site... Thanks to [@billinkc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2131/billinkc).

I had the thought in the back of my mind that maybe the graph had to much data to display but guess it never clicked.

I modified the graph's Category Groups to be an expression for grouping by the hour not just the full date value: `=Hour(Fields!CapturedTime.Value)`

That allowed the graph to be prettified into this:
[image]